# calculation of convex conjugate

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

$X$ is a Banach space and $X^{*}$ denotes its dual. Let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary convex function. The *Fenchel conjugate* of $f$ is the function $f^{*}:X^{*}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, defined as
\begin{equation}
f^{*}(x^{*})= \sup_{x\in X}\left(\left\langle x,x^{*}\right\rangle -f(x)\right).
\end{equation}
My question is how to express the conjugate of f ,when 
\begin{equation}
\sup_{x\in X}\left(\left\langle x,x^{*}\right\rangle -f(\alpha  x)\right).
\end{equation}
where $a\neq 0$ i a given constant.

My idea: We set $\alpha x=y$. Then $x=\frac{y}{\alpha}$. We have

\begin{align*}
f^{*}_{\alpha}(x^{*})&= \sup_{x\in X}\left(\left\langle x,x^{*}\right\rangle -f(\alpha x)\right)\\
&=\sup_{y\in X}\left(\left\langle \frac{y}{\alpha},x^{*}\right\rangle -f(y)\right)\\
&=\sup_{y\in X}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\left\langle x^{*},y\right\rangle -f(y)\right)\\
&=\sup_{y\in X}\left(\left\langle \frac{x^{*}}{\alpha},y\right\rangle -f(y)\right)\\
&=f^{*}_{\alpha}\left(\frac{x^{*}}{\alpha} \right).
\end{align*}

Is the above correct?

Comment: looks fine to me, apart from the start of your first line which is incorrect (it's not $f^\star(x^\star)$ maybe you could write it $f^\star_\alpha(x^\star)$ (Ps: maybe add the tag "convex-analysis" which is relevant here imho.

Comment: you may want to look up "composition with invertible linear mapping" which is a more general statement than yours and is well known, for a simple one see: http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/conj.pdf page 7-12

Comment: @tibL Thank you for your kind comments.